# Bug of cocos2d/cocosbuilder or not: Why timeline 0(sequenceId) run automatically?

Tags: iphone, ios, cocos2d-iphone, cocosbuilder

Here are my tools: `CocosBuilder-2.1/CCBReader-2.1/cocos2d-iphone-2.0`

I created `TestNode.ccb`(root object is CCNode), in it I create 2 timeline,`@"t0name"`(2s long) and `@"t1name"`(2s long), 
root node is set to custom class `TestNode`

I created `TestNode.h`:

```
#import "CCBAnimationManager.h"

@interface TestNode : CCNode <CCBAnimationManagerDelegate>{

}
@property (nonatomic, assign) BOOL condition;
@property (nonatomic, assign) BOOL t1Played;

-(void)playAnimation:(NSString *)name;
-(void)playAnimation;

@end
```

and here is the `TestNode.m`:

```
#import "TestNode.h"
#import "CCBReader.h"

@implementation TestNode

@synthesize condition;
@synthesize t1Played;

-(void)playAnimation:(NSString *)name{
    CCBAnimationManager* animationManager = self.userObject;
    [animationManager runAnimationsForSequenceNamed:name];
}

-(void)playAnimation{
    if(self.condition==YES) {
        [self playAnimation:@"t1name"];
        self.t1played=YES;
    }else{
        [self playAnimation:@"t0name"];
    }
}

-(void)didLoadFromCCB{
    CCBAnimationManager* animationManager = self.userObject;
    animationManager.delegate = self;
}

-(void)completedAnimationSequenceNamed:(NSString *)pName{
    if (self.t1played==YES) {
        NSLog(@"t1played");
    }else{
        [self playAnimation];
    }
}

@end
```

There is also a main layer (`TestScene.h/.m`), in this scene i will add `CCNode` and some thing else...

Normal case:

In the main layer's `onEnter(`), I add an instance of `TestNode` and call it's playAnimation, according to the code above, the timeline named `@"t0name"` will be played forever, and what really happened is the same to my assumption.

Strange case:
In the main layer's `onEnter()`, I add an instance of `TestNode` and call it's `playAnimation`, AND schedule a function `[self schedule:@selector(changeTestNodeCondition) interval:1.0];` this function(`changeTestNodeCondition`) just set `TestNode`'s condition to YES, according to the code above, the timeline named `@"t0name"` wil be played once(`t0'` length is 2s), then timeline named `@"t1name"` will be played once, then console will print "t1played" and everything stop, but what happened is:

1. timeline named `@"t0name"` played once
2. timeline named `@"t1name"` played once
3. console print "t1played"
4. timeline named `@"t0name"` played again
5. console print "t1played" again

Why step4 happened? it cause `completedAnimationSequenceNamed:(NSString *) name` is called again and console print "t1played" again(step 5)

I checkd the `TestNode.ccb`, both timeline has no chained timeline, both timeline unchecked auto play, `@"t0name"` has `sequenceId 0`, `@"t0name"` has `sequenceId 1`, is `timeline 0` autoplayed ??? Why???

I did another interesting experiment: I change timeline `@"t0name"` sequence id to 1, change timeline `@"t1name`" sequence id to 2 (edit the ccb file directly using any text editor), following thing happen:

1. timeline named @"t0name" played once
2. timeline named @"t1name" played once
3. console print "t1played"
4. console print "t1played" again and again and again... dead loop

I guess in this case `CCAnimationManager` try to play `timeline 0`, but `timeline 0` is not there so there is no animation can be seen but the "play" operation is called and then `completedAnimationSequenceNamed:(NSString *) name` is called!